# JQuery 2.2.0 loading twice and throws error "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' "

Tags: jquery

I'm registering JQuery from Global.asax, something like this -

```
 string JQueryVer = "2.2.0";
            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
            {
                Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
                DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
                CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
                CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
                CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
                LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
            });
```

This code works fine for all pages except one. I tried looking, whether jquery is registered twice but that is not the case. Strangely, if I remove Range validator from the page(that throws error), jquery is not registering twice.

I want to know the possible reason for this scenario. Also, how can I check from the Global.asax that "Load jquery only if it does not exists"?

Looking forward for help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding $.noConflict();

Comment: No luck. Do you know how to write such kind of jquery noConflict code from Global.asax? Basically, jquery should only load if its not present.

Comment: can you see this once https://forum.jquery.com/topic/if-typeof-jquery-undefined-not-working

Comment: Tried this Sarath but no luck! In other pages it loads jquery-2.2.0.min.js but for only one page, it loads jquery-2.2.0.min.js as well as jquery-2.2.0.js.